# How to add `:include` to default_scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Searching the 'net, I found that I should use `:include`, but that does not seem to change the SQL query that is generated:

```
def Post #model
  default_scope :order => 'created_at DESC', :include => :author
end
```

With or without the `:include`, the SQL is the same (i.e. it is only selecting from the posts table).

What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

What if you do

```
default_scope { includes(:author).order('created_at ASC') }
```

This is the way that it’s documented in the Rails API for [`default_scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-default_scope) & [`scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope), rather than the hash parameter method you're using.

Comment: Yes, using that style, but with `includes` (plural), works. Also found that using the hash-style, using `:joins` instead of `:include` works.

Comment: Include on its own is usually interpreted as the Ruby include keyword and it doesn't like it :)

Comment: @Ghoti `include` isn’t a keyword, it’s a method (`defined?(include) #=> "method"`), and thus *could* be overridden. Of course `:include` is just an unrelated symbol.

Comment: in rails 4 you must use blocks for this

`default_scope { includes(:author) }`